# Having trouble with CS50 Greedy.c problem

Tags: c, cs50, greedy

I recently enrolled myself into the CS50 class offered by EDx.com. I'm currently having trouble with the greedy.c problem is pset1. I feel like the problem is that my do-while loops aren't actually looping. Regardless of the input I give the program I get 4 coins every time. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
int n = 0;
int count = 0;
int cents = 0;
do
{
    printf("How much change is owed?\n");
    get_int();

}
while(n > 0);

do
{
    count++;
    n -=25;
}
 while(n >= 25);

 do
 {
     count++;
     n -=10;
 }
 while(n >= 10);

 do
 {
     count++;
     n -=5;
 }
 while(n >= 5);

 do
 {
     count++;
     n -=1;
 }
 while(n >=1);


printf("Here is %i coins\n", count);

}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Go to stackoverflow.com's [help], and read the instructions for creating a [mcve]. Unfortunately, until the question meets all the requirements of a [mcve], the fundamental laws of logic of our shared universe forbid anyone to help you.

Comment: Take a debugger and step through the code. This is a great moment to learn how to debug!

Comment: `get_int();` I think this function call does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code:

```
get_int();
```

Does nothing. 
get_int will get and return an int, however you never actually put that value in a variable, that is the reason the input does not change the program's behavior.

Perhaps you meant to write something like this:

```
n = get_int();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick. I did what you suggested and it didn't cause any errors, however the program doesn't accept any number I give it as a valid integer. It just keeps re-prompting me for "How much change is owed?".

Answer (score 0):

The do while loops will always execute once that's why you're always getting 4 coins, then you're also not assigning the input value to n.

The first do while will run infinitely if n > 0 so change it to:

```
do {
    printf("How much change is owed?\n");
    n = get_int();
} while (n == 0);
```

next your do whiles will add to count even when they shouldn't, the below should be better.

```
while (n >= 25) {
    count++;
    n -= 25;
}
```

Good luck with CS50, thats where I started as well, it's difficult but really sets you up to learn to think.